# All PHP turns to undefined when i use my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

When i use my navigation bar and switch page, for some reason all of my php turns undefined. I know that the cause of that is my new no-refresh navigation, basically the site doesnt refresh when im going to another page. So when i use my navigation bar all of the user-based php code turns undefined (things such as username, logo, balance etc).

Heres the new navigation code

```
    $(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }});
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
        }
        return false;  
    });
});
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    }});
});
```

And here's a example of php code that turnes undefined

```
<div class="overview-h1">Welcome back <?php echo $user['name']; ?>!</div>
```

Comment: Try posting the basic part of your PHP like how the user object is generated as PHP is where the issue is happening.

Comment: Is this line `<div class="overview-h1">Welcome back <?php echo $user['name']; ?>!</div>` inside $('#content').html(data) ?

Comment: Yeah it is in a separate file

Comment: The definition of `$user[]` is not going to persist from page to page if you don't send it somehow. [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are a good way to handle persistent data if you want it to follow a user for a while

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if im right here, but i think that the `$('#content').html(data);` is only saving html when u switch page, thats atleast what i think. Altough im not entirely sure how to solve it